# Show posts in one page from different wordpress installs

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show posts from my sub-directory in one page with wp_query loop. So I tried this code:

```
<?php   
    require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/picture/wp-load.php'); 
    $args = array(
        // 'cat' => 3, // Only source posts from a specific category
        'posts_per_page' => 10 // Specify how many posts you'd like to display
    );
    $latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );  
    if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
            $latest_posts->the_post(); ?>                
            <li>
               <div class="media"> 
                   <a class="media-left" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> 
                      <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> <?php } ?> 
                   </a>    
                   <div class="media-body"> 
                       <a class="catg_title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </li>
        <?php } 
     } else { 
           echo '<p>There are no posts available</p>'; 
     } 
     wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

Then again in another place but same page i use same code but i want to show posts from different folder means different wp site.

```
<?php   
    require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/video/wp-load.php'); 
    $args = array(
        // 'cat' => 3, // Only source posts from a specific category
        'posts_per_page' => 10 // Specify how many posts you'd like to display
    );
    $latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );  
    if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
            $latest_posts->the_post(); ?>    
            <li>
                <div class="media"> 
                   <a class="media-left" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> 
                      <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> <?php } ?> 
                   </a>    
                   <div class="media-body"> 
                       <a class="catg_title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </li>
       <?php } 
    } else { 
          echo '<p>There are no posts available</p>'; 
    } 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
 ?>
```

But problem is its showing posts from picture forlder. in this way, i use several folder but every folder show posts from 1st folder. how can i close first folder then show 2nd folder's posts?
[This is where i want to show posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vwIq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Wordpress Multisite** was designed for this. After [enabling Multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) you can use the [switch_to_blog()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) function. After running your code, you can switch back to the original blog:

```
switch_to_blog($blog_id);
// Echo posts
restore_current_blog();
```

Comment: you sure? because i install multisite first, but i cant call a specific blog by id then i re-install all things again

Comment: Can you check the id of each blog with <?= get_current_blog_id() ?>?

Comment: as you said i uninstall all sites and re-install wp with multisite enable. then i try to use this code https://pastebin.com/AkUw1VK7 and output is 'Error establishing a database connection'

Comment: Are you sure that your config is correct? That error is generic and unrelated to this issue.

Comment: yes. 100% sure.my site is working.only its showing error on test page where i put these code

Comment: Have you imported your previous sites into Wordpress MU? What are the site IDs for each blog? You can check this in the database if you're unable to print the codes.

Comment: i install a fresh copy with multisite enable.then create 3 site for testing.so blog ids is 2,3,4.

Comment: is there any solution for this problem,since i am stuck at this so i cant finish my work.

Comment: It's impossible to debug without additional info. This might help:https://scotty-t.com/2012/03/13/switch_to_blog-is-an-unfunny-nightmare/

Comment: i found the cause. its because wp installation can be called from another directory by wp_quary but when it is multisite, it can't be. you have to call it from same folder where wp is installed.then it will work. might be, because database structure is different when wp-multisite is enable.